# Looking for conformation that my probability calculations are correct

Tags: probability

Hello I am trying to work some problems that do not have solutions. I will post them and then my thoughts and if anyone could please tell me if I am correct or where I am going wrong that would be very good.[image]

I am wanting to calculate things such as $P(X \le Y )$, $Cov(X,Y)$ , $E[X|Y=1]$ and the moment generating functions of Y.

Here is my thoughts:

For $P(X \le Y)$ I summed up those cases in which this actually is true, and I came to the solution of $0.6$

For the $Cov(X,Y)$ I wanted to use that it is equal to $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$

I calculated $E(XY)=-0.85$,

then I wrote on the marginal functions for X and Y and used that to find $E(X)=-0.25$ and $E(Y)= 0.4$ and thus a $Cov(X,Y)=-0.75$

For $E(X|Y=1)$ I did the cases individually and then I summed, and got a final answer of $0.2$.

For the moment generating function of Y I got something like $e^{-t}+e^{t}+e^{2t}$

Again, I am trying to prepare for my exam by doing old problems from past times, but there are no solutions. So I would have no way of knowing if I am actually understanding or am completely off. Thanks anyone for any time.

Comment: For the mgf you want $(0.45)e^{-t}+(0.25)e^t+(0.30)e^{2t}$. I think all the other answers are right. (I did the calculations, but my arithmetic is not fully reliable.)

Comment: Thank you, I also posted a similar question but with continuous probability, maybe if you have spare time you could take a look at this as well?           http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541727/looking-for-conformation-on-probability-questions?noredirect=1#comment3139474_1541727