# Looking for someone to help check over probability questions

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Hi I am preparing for exam and am doing old exams. So I thought I will try them and post and see if anyone can please tell me if I am wrong or not etc.

[image]

What I tried;

a) My question about this is, should I calculate $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}y(x+y)dxdy=\frac{5}{6}$$  or should I just calculate $$\int_{0}^{1}yf_{y}(Y)dy=\frac{7}{12}$$

where $f_{y}(Y)=(y+\frac{1}{2})$

Which is the correct method to do such? ( I would think the second, but im not sure)

b)

$$f(X|Y=y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{y}(Y)}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x(x+\frac{1}{2})dx= \frac{7}{12}$$

c)
$P[X^{2} \gt Y]$

This one im not as sure on, as the bounds of integration are a bit confusing. When I draw it out,it seems like I should do the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} (x+y) dy dx=\frac{7}{20}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} (x+y) dx dy=\frac{9}{20}$$

I really appreciate anyone who takes the time to try it out and let me know. This will help me to know if I am understanding or not, Thanks a lot anyone in advance for any comments. The exam is coming up very soon so it is rather important that I figure this out as soon as possible. I have placed a bounty to try to help with this and I added more of my own work to help clarify.

Comment: I doubt many people will be interested in doing the calculations for you. Just trust yourself with the calculation part. Your approach is correct btw.
Have a look at these solved examples http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_5_solved_prob.php

Comment: In part d) however, I don't understand what you've done. Should have found $P(X = x | Y = 1)$ and then computed the expectation.

Comment: @mathnoob Thanks. and in regards to that, yes im not sure, I thought I would have to calculate f(x,1) , but x can be one of 3 possibible values no?

Comment: Yes x can take 3 values when $Y = 1$, but probability of one of those values is 0 i.e. $X = - 1$. So the conditional probabilities are 
$P(X = 0 | Y = 1) = 0.2/0.3$ and $P(X = 2 | Y = 1) = 0.1/0.3$

Comment: For part (c) you have $X^2 > Y$ which takes the shape of the standard parabola on $\{(x,y) | 0 < x,y < 1\}$. Now you have to determine whether the region below or above is the one we want. By simple plugging in such as the point $\Big( \frac{1}{2}, 0 \Big)$ we see that the inequality is satisfied. So for the integration we want $\{ (x,y) | 0 < y < x^2, \hspace{.1cm} 0 < x < 1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Expected value of $x$ is the sum of $xf(x)$ for possible $x$, where $f(x)$ is the probability of the event happening. In the case of a continuous function, we simply sum the rectangular prisms creating the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}y(x+y)dxdy=\\
\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{yx^2}{2}+y^2x\right)\biggr|^1_0dy=\\
\left(\frac{y^2x^2}{4}+\frac{y^3x}{3}\right)\biggr|^1_0\biggr|^1_0=\frac{7}{12}$$
Your logic was there for the first integral, but somewhere in the computation you had an error.

b) Again, your logic is fine for the expected value on this one. Simply integrating over the possibilities,

$$\int_{0}^{1}x(x+\frac{1}{2})dx = \frac{7}{12}$$

c) In this case, $x^2>y \implies x>\sqrt{y}$, so integrate
$$\int_0^1\int_\sqrt{y}^1(x+y)dxdy = \frac{7}{20}$$

The first method also works by integrating over the possible $y$ for a given $x$, but the second integral does not work since you're using $x \in (0,\sqrt{y})$ and $y \in (0,1)$, which doesn't follow the assumption that $x^2>y$. Take $x = 0.25 \in (0,\sqrt{0.9})$ and $y = 0.9 \in (0,1)$.
$$0.25^2 \ngtr 0.9$$

Comment: So for the first part, either integral is correct, ( just a mistake in computation I made for one of them)?

Comment: @Quality Correct.

Comment: thanks, possibly you would be able to also help with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541727/looking-for-confirmation-on-probability-questions